# Does Bloomberg Terminal have access to CRSP "permno"s, Compustat GVKEYs?

Tags: data, bloomberg

CRSP has a nice, *permanent* identifier system for securities known as "permno"s. I don't have access to a Bloomberg terminal, but am considering the investment. Does the Bloomberg terminal know these identifiers?

What about other identifiers? I'm sure it know CUSIPs. What about Compustat's "GVKEY"s?

Thanks.

Comment: Damn. No GVKEY presumably then. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexC, could you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on the Bloomberg Terminal. But just looking at it now I see it knows the CUSIP, the ISIN, the SEDOL, the WPK (wertpapierkennummer) and the SICOVAM. I don't believe it knows the CSRP-permno as far as I know. It does not do a particularly good job of linking to other information systems, being more of a self contained system itself. But perhaps there are special functions for that purpose that I don't know .

Comment: Managed to confirm with Bloomberg, no permno, no gvkey.